# Renaming Email Attachment in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, email-attachments

I had a script that would rename my email attachments in Python 2.7, however since recently updating to Python 3.6, I am having problems figuring this out with all the changes.  I ditched my old script as it appeared to not be applicable with the newer version of Python.

Using the script below, how do I change the name of my email attachments?
It seems to work fine for sending them, however I cannot figure out how to properly rename the attachments.  Thanks for any assistance.

```
# Importing Modules
import smtplib,imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage

sender = "Me - Storm Alerts <myEmail@myJob.com>"
recipient = "yourEmail@yourJob.com"

msgTxt = "D:/testFolder/MSG.txt"
map2attach = "D:/testFolder/warningsMap.png"

# Create a text/plain message
with open(msgTxt) as fp:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())
    with open(map2attach, 'rb') as fp:
      img_data = fp.read()
    msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image',subtype=imghdr.what(None, img_data))
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition',map2attach,filename='EmailTest.png')

msg['Subject'] = "NWS Alert"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipient

s = smtplib.SMTP('mail.myServer.com')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out for anyone that needs any future help.

I had to replace the following two lines:

```
msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image',subtype=imghdr.what(None, img_data))
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition',map2attach,filename='EmailTest.png')
```

With the following line:

```
msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image',subtype=imghdr.what(None,img_data),filename="EmailTest.png")
```